# getting row index of a specified row using java script

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get the rowindex of a passed row number. I tried using rowIndex[2]. but i dont get it. here is the code. please help me. thanks in advance..

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   <!-- For jQuery --> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <button onclick = "replaceContent('tabledata')"> Click to Load  </button>
            <table id="tabledata">

            </table>              
        </div>

        <script> 
            function replaceContent(tableid)
            {
                var targetDiv = $('#' + tableid).closest("div").prop("id");
                var content = "<table> <tr> <td> One</td></tr><tr> <td> One</td></tr><tr> <td> One</td></tr><tr> <td> One</td></tr><tr> <td> One</td></tr></table>";                
                $('#' + targetDiv).html(content);         
                var x = document.getElementById("tabledata").rows[1];
                alert (x.rowIndex);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you close your table `</table>`?

Comment: Why do this `var targetDiv = $('#' + tableid).closest("div").prop("id"); $('#' + targetDiv)`?

Comment: You create it then you destroy it and then try to use it. _Hint:_ tabledata

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your `<table id="tabledata">` inside HTML, there's no need to create another one dynamically, use the existent one as cached element reference.
(Also, remember to close your tag properly `</table>`)

```js
function replaceContent(tableid) {
  
  var $table = $("#"+ tableid);
  
  // Don't put <table> inside content
  var content = "<tr><td> One</td></tr><tr> <td> Two</td></tr><tr> <td> Three</td></tr><tr> <td> Four</td></tr><tr> <td> Five</td></tr>";    
  
  $table.html(content);         
  var x = $table.find("tr").eq(1);   // Get second Row HTML for test
  alert (x.html());

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <button onclick="replaceContent('tabledata')"> Click to Load  </button>
  <table id="tabledata"></table>              
</div>
```